# how can I plot two infinite series of different range at a time

Tags: plotting

how can I plot two infinite series of different range at a time. I am new in mathematica it will be great help if someone help me in this issue

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way might be

```
u[t_,x_,max_]:=1/2+Sum[ 1/(n Pi) ((-1)^n -1) Exp[-n^2 t] Sin[n x],{n,1,max}]+
   Sum[ 1/(n Pi) ((-1)^n -1) Exp[-n^2 t] Cos[n x],{n,2,max}];
max=10;
times={0,0.01,0.1,1,10};
Plot[ Evaluate@Table[u[t,x,max],{t,times}],{x,0,10},PlotLegends->times]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can adjust the number of terms to sum over and the `x` range, as in

```
max=20;
times={0,0.01,0.1,1,10};
Plot[ Evaluate@Table[u[t,x,max],{t,times}],{x,0,30},PlotLegends->times]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]